# Intermittent terminated: Application failed to start: not available

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am using Google cloudrun to run my NodeJs application.
Most of the time it is working without any issues, however once in a while I am getting the the error `"terminated: Application failed to start: not available"` and starts getting 503 errors.

I have gone through the other answers, but it did not help in my case as it is not intermittent issues.

Could you please help me understand the cause for the error and how can we fix this?

Configuration of the micro-service is as given below:

- CPU - 1
- Memory - 1 GiB
- Concurrency - 40
- Request timeout - 300 seconds
- Execution environment - Second generation
- Min instances - 1
- Max instances - 100

Thank you,
KK

Comment: Can you share your code and your configuration?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have updated the configuration details. 
I am not sure which part of the code you are asking for, does the server initialization code suffice?

Comment: Maybe yes!! I have only one side of the problem. I have to server power, but not what you are running on! What's your App code? What are you initializing? Do you depend on external resources? Do you have database connexion?

Comment: Let me update the question with the server initialization. 
And it is a web service and usually gets around 100 requests/second

Comment: I can see that you are using [Second Generation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/execution-environments) as Execution environment which is currently in preview stage which might have limited support. can you revert back to Gen 1 and try?